# How to restrict movement for a length or period of time (logic bricks)?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

How to to restrict the translation (or rotation) in Z axis for a length (yellow line) and activate it after (blue line)? Using only logic bricks.

[image: movement]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to add a **Float** property to the 'yellow' area. I called mine "Bar". no reason. (if it isn't area you want to determine it by then skip this step and go with a *Delay* sensor rather than *Collision*, *Near*, or *Ray*)

Use a *Collision*, *Near*, or *Ray* (depending on your preferences and needs)sensor to determine when the "Bar" property is close enough to invoke the constraint behavior.

Via an *And* controller, link your sensor to a *Constraint* actuator and set the axis based on whatever axis is "up" in your diagram. Turn on *true level triggering* on the sensor.

[image: Finished results!]